# How to request a file which is last in dir.txt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

super newbie here,

I have a dir.txt file in server with a list of .txt files in the folder. I want to load the last file in the list and load it into another function to be put in a div. So far i can load text into div with a direct file name like "content/bugun.txt". But i want this path to be a variable which is set from dir.txt.

I can also console.log the dir.txt but couldn't make the connection. Contents of dir.txt are like this;

```
20200410.txt
20200411.txt
20200412.txt
20200413.txt
20200414.txt
20200415.txt
20200416.txt
20200417.txt
```

here is my fetch for dir.txt

```
<script>
fetch('content/dir.txt')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then((names) => {
    console.log(names)
  })</script>
```

and here is my code for pushing txt to div

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function loadDoc() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("deneme").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "content/20200417.txt", true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: You need a web server application that serves the file

Comment: Split the `this.responseText` by new lines into an array (my_array for example: `my_array = this.responseText.split(/\r?\n/)`), than select last one as `last = my_array[my_array.length - 1]`